# JS: variable doesn't get stored correctly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this dice rolling script and I can't seem to get the script to display the correct value of the players dice's, the banks dice's seem to display the correct value, this is essential because for the game to work it needs to compare the output of the players dices and the banks dices, I have placed window.alert in the if/else functions to view if speleruitkomst works.

VAR LIST:

```
speleruitkomst = players dice
bankuitkomst = banks dice
Rekening = how much the player has in his bank
Inzet = how much a user bets on the game.
```

The game is called Higher/Lower

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html>
<head>

<title>Hoger Lager</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dobbelsteen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/canvas.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/canvas.css">
</head>

<body>
<canvas id='bank' width="600" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id='speler' width="600" height="500"></canvas>
<body onload="beginSpel()">
<div id="wrapper">
<article>
                <button id="Hoger" onClick="Hoger()">Hoger</button>
                <button id="Lager" onClick="Lager()">Lager</button>
                <button id="verhoogInzet" onClick="verhoogInzet()">+</button>
                <button id="verlaagInzet" onClick="verlaagInzet()">-</button>
                <button id="reset" onClick="resetSpel()">Reset</button>
        </article>     
<br></div>


</body>
</html>
```

dobbelsteen.js

```
/*function tekensteen(x)
{
steennummer = x;
beeldsteenaf();
}*/
function tekenbank()
{
        canvas = document.getElementById("bank");
        pen = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        pen.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        nummer=1;
        gooiDobbelsteen();
        tekenDobbelsteen(nummer, ogen);
        bankuitkomst = ogen;
        nummer=2;
        gooiDobbelsteen();
        bankuitkomst=bankuitkomst+ogen;
        tekenDobbelsteen(nummer, ogen);
}

function tekenspeler()
{
        canvas = document.getElementById("speler");
        pen = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        pen.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        nummer=3;
        gooiDobbelsteen();
        tekenDobbelsteen(nummer, ogen);
        var speleruitkomst = ogen;
        nummer=4;
        gooiDobbelsteen();
        speleruitkomst = bankuitkomst+ogen;
        tekenDobbelsteen(nummer, ogen);
}



function tekenVierkant()
{
                pen.beginPath();
                pen.lineWidth=8;
                pen.rect(xoff + 0, yoff + 0,240,240);
                pen.strokeStyle="Khaki";
                pen.stroke();
}

function tekenOog1()
{
                pen.beginPath();
                pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
                pen.arc(xoff + 60,yoff + 60,20,0,2*Math.PI);
                pen.stroke();
                pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
                pen.fill();
}

function tekenOog2()
{
                pen.beginPath();
                pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
                pen.arc(xoff + 60,yoff + 120,20,0,2*Math.PI);
                pen.stroke();
                pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
                pen.fill();
}

function tekenOog3(pos)
{
pen.beginPath();
pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
pen.arc(xoff + 60,yoff + 180,20,0,2*Math.PI);
pen.stroke();
pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
pen.fill();
}

function tekenOog4(pos)
{
pen.beginPath();
pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
pen.arc(xoff + 120,yoff + 60,20,0,2*Math.PI);
pen.stroke();
pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
pen.fill();
}

function tekenOog5(pos)
{
                pen.beginPath();
                pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
                pen.arc(xoff + 120,yoff + 120,20,0,2*Math.PI);
                pen.stroke();
                pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
                pen.fill();
}

function tekenOog6(pos)
{
                pen.beginPath();
                pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
                pen.arc(xoff + 120,yoff + 180,20,0,2*Math.PI);
                pen.stroke();
                pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
                pen.fill();
}

function tekenOog7(pos)
{
                pen.beginPath();
                pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
                pen.arc(xoff + 180,yoff + 60,20,0,2*Math.PI);
                pen.stroke();
                pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
                pen.fill();
}

function tekenOog8(pos)
{
                pen.beginPath();
                pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
                pen.arc(xoff + 180,yoff + 120,20,0,2*Math.PI);
                pen.stroke();
                pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
                pen.fill();
}

function tekenOog9(pos)
{
                pen.beginPath();
                pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
                pen.arc(xoff + 180,yoff + 180,20,0,2*Math.PI);
                pen.stroke();
                pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
                pen.fill();
}






//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


function wisTekening()
{
                var canvas = document.getElementById('figuur1');
                var pen = canvas.getContext('2d');
                pen.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function waarde1()
{
tekenVierkant();
tekenOog5();
}

function waarde2()
{
tekenVierkant();
tekenOog1();
tekenOog9();
}

function waarde3()
{
tekenVierkant();
tekenOog1();
tekenOog5();
tekenOog9();
}

function waarde4()
{
tekenVierkant();
tekenOog1();
tekenOog3();
tekenOog7();
tekenOog9();
}

function waarde5()
{
tekenVierkant();
tekenOog1();
tekenOog3();
tekenOog5();
tekenOog7();
tekenOog9();
}

function waarde6()
{
tekenVierkant();
tekenOog1();
tekenOog2();
tekenOog3();
tekenOog7();
tekenOog8();
tekenOog9();
}

function gooiDobbelsteen()
{
ogen = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
return ogen;
}

function tekenDobbelsteen(nummer, ogen)
{
switch (nummer){
  case 1:
                xoff = 10;
                yoff = 60;
                break;
case 2:
                xoff = 260;
                yoff = 60;
                break;
 case 3:
                xoff = 10;
                yoff = 60;
                break;
case 4:
                xoff = 260;
                yoff = 60;
                break;
}
switch (ogen){
  case 1:
  waarde1();
break;
case 2:
waarde2();
break;
case 3:
 waarde3();
break;
case 4:
waarde4();
break;
case 5: waarde5();
break;
  case 6: waarde6();
 break;
}
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

canvas.js

```
function beginSpel()
{
        saldo();
        tekenbank();
        laadcanvasbank();
        laadcanvasspeler();
        disableBtn(false);
}
function saldo()
{
        speleruitkomst=0;
        Rekening=500;
}


function disableBtn(x) {
    document.getElementById("Hoger").disabled = x;
        document.getElementById("Lager").disabled = x;
        document.getElementById("verhoogInzet").disabled = x;  
        document.getElementById("verlaagInzet").disabled = x;
}
function speler()
{
bah();
}


function laadcanvasbank()
{
canvas = document.getElementById("bank");
pen = canvas.getContext("2d");
showFillText();
}

function showFillText()
{
Inzet = 10;
pen.fillStyle = '#black';
pen.font = 'italic bold 30px sans-serif';
pen.textBaseline = 'bottom';
pen.fillText('Bank:', 10, 40);
}

function laadcanvasspeler()
{
        canvas1 = document.getElementById("speler");
        pen2 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        Inzetten();
}

function showFillText2()
{
pen2.fillStyle = '#black';
pen2.font = 'italic bold 30px sans-serif';
pen2.textBaseline = 'bottom';
pen2.fillText('Gebruiker:', 10, 40);
}

function Inzetten()
{
showFillText2();
pen2.fillStyle = '#black';
pen2.font = 'italic bold 30px sans-serif';
pen2.textBaseline = 'bottom';
pen2.fillText('Saldo: '+ Rekening, 20, 80);
pen2.fillText('Hoeveel wilt u inzetten: '+ Inzet+ ' punten', 20, 120);
}

function verhoogInzet()
{
Inzet = Inzet+10;
if (Inzet > Rekening)
{
        Inzet=Rekening;
}
pen2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
Inzetten();
}

function verlaagInzet()
{
Inzet = Inzet-10;
if (Inzet < 0)
{
        Inzet=0;
}
pen2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
Inzetten();
}


function Hoger()
{
disableBtn(true);
if (bankuitkomst < speleruitkomst)
{
        window.alert("speleruitkomst: " + speleruitkomst + " Bankuitkomst: " + bankuitkomst);
        pen2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        tekenspeler();
        pen2.fillStyle = '#black';
        pen2.fillText('U heeft ' + Inzet +' punten gewonnen!', 20, 340);
        Rekening=Rekening+Inzet;
        pen2.fillText('Uw nieuwe Saldo: '+ Rekening + ' punten', 20, 380);
}
else
{
        window.alert("speleruitkomst: " + speleruitkomst + " Bankuitkomst: " + bankuitkomst);
        pen2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        tekenspeler();
        pen2.fillStyle = '#black';
        pen2.fillText('U heeft ' + Inzet +' punten verloren!', 20, 340);
        Rekening=Rekening-Inzet;
        pen2.fillText('Uw nieuwe Saldo: '+ Rekening + ' punten', 20, 380);
}      
}

function Lager()
{
disableBtn(true);
if (bankuitkomst > speleruitkomst)
{
        window.alert("speleruitkomst: " + speleruitkomst + " Bankuitkomst: " + bankuitkomst);
        pen2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        tekenspeler();
        pen2.fillStyle = '#black';
        pen2.fillText('U heeft ' + Inzet +' punten gewonnen!', 20, 340);
        Rekening=Rekening+Inzet;
        pen2.fillText('Uw nieuwe Saldo: '+ Rekening + ' punten', 20, 380);
}
else
{
        window.alert("speleruitkomst: " + speleruitkomst + " Bankuitkomst: " + bankuitkomst);
        pen2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        tekenspeler();
        pen2.fillStyle = '#black';
        pen2.fillText('U heeft ' + Inzet +' punten verloren!', 20, 340);
        Rekening=Rekening-Inzet;
        pen2.fillText('Uw nieuwe Saldo: '+ Rekening + ' punten', 20, 380);
}
}


function resetSpel()
{
        if (Rekening === 0)
        {
    Rekening=500;
        disableBtn(false);
        pen.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        pen2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        tekenbank();
        laadcanvasbank();
        laadcanvasspeler();
        }
else
{

        disableBtn(false);
        pen.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        pen2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        tekenbank();
        laadcanvasbank();
        laadcanvasspeler();
}
}
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Reduce your problem to a [**Minimal** complete verifiable example](/help/mcve). Walls of code are not useful questions for people in the future. Particularly unformatted, inconsistently-indented, uncommented walls of code.

Comment: Also note that you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declre your variables.